# Unable to run rails generate social_stream:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, social-stream

It gives me following error. What should I do?

I'm using rails 4.2.5.1

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'social_stream'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
        from E:/messla/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `generate_or_destroy'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

first write your Gemfile

```
gem 'social_stream', :git => 'git://github.com/ging/social_stream.git'
```

and you can run

```
bundle update
```

Or run

```
rails generate social_stream:install
```

For explanation [look this](https://github.com/ging/social_stream/wiki/SETUP-TIPS-FOR-DUMMIES)

Comment: Again after running rails generate social_stream:install it tells now new thing.{The git source git://github.com/ging/social_stream.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application}Following that I ran 'bundle install' it tells run 'bundle update' before running your application that stuff repeats itself any idea?

Comment: It works on  github  but I had to make a slight change in gem file..and then load your strategy .Roger that?